# How to convert a byte type data to UUID in python

Tags: python, uuid

I am reading the UUID from my board as
`b"\x93S4E2\x8d\x9e\x8f\xe9\x11\xc1z\xd0U\x95'"`

How to convert or format this to obtain a 128-bit UUID that reads
`[279555d0-7ac1-11e9-8f93-8d3245345393]`

Comment: The question is being downvoted because there's no clear correlation between the binary string and the UUID shown. Please explain how you got from that particular input to that particular output. And please use the "Edit" button on the original post to do so, in the interests of maximizing this question's value to future readers. Answers are not for adding detail to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python UUID library will normally cover most of the situations that you need for UUIDs.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

The result I'm get doesn't match your expected output 100% but I wonder if you have a typo in your question.

This is what I did:

```py
import uuid

raw_id = b"\x93S4E2\x8d\x9e\x8f\xe9\x11\xc1z\xd0U\x95'"
dev_uuid = uuid.UUID(int=int.from_bytes(raw_id, 'little'))
print(f"Device UUID = {dev_uuid}")
```

Which gave the output:

```
Device UUID = 279555d0-7ac1-11e9-8f9e-8d3245345393
```